# aggregate multiple rows based on time ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

i do have a `customer`and he use over a specific period of time different devices, tracked with a `valid_from` and `valid_to` date. but, every time something changes for this device there will be a new row written without any visible changes for the row based data, besides a new valid from/to.

[image: data looks like that]

what i'm trying to do is to `aggregate` the first two rows into one, same for row `3` and `4`, while leaving `5` and `6` as they are. all my solutions i came up so far with are working for a usage history for the user not switching back to `device a`. everything keeps failing.

i'd really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, if you have any code from your attempts it might be beneficial to provide also

Comment: This question was answered many times already. Please read this article [Grouping Sequence Ranges](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915680).

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the previous `valid_to` is the same as the current `valid_from`, then you can use `lag()` to identify where a new grouping starts.  Then use a cumulative sum to calculate the grouping and finally aggregation:

```
select cust, act_dev, min(valid_from), max(valid_to)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_valid_to = valid_from then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by cust order by valid_from) as grouping
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(valid_to) over (partition by cust, act_dev order by valid_from) as prev_valid_to
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by cust, act_dev, grouping;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f598802ef2a72efc96bd0606fc4bd1d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It is not giving the expected output. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b1dd282b346614c24280f817de6172f)